# NotORM with existing class

Tags: php, mysql, orm, notorm

I'm looking in to using NotORM for a project (no code has been written yet).

I get that NotORM can make an object based on MySQL tables. What I don't quite understand is how I use it if I have an existing class in place. Should I inject NotORM in to the class? But then how do I use it to load/save from the db?

I guess the main problem I am trying to understand is if I have a class that I save to the db over multiple tables (let's call it MyClass), I understand why an ORM is a good idea, as the class may be stored over multiple tables in the db, but what if MyClass has some methods that do other stuff (for example maybe it talks to an external api elsewhere)? Just loading straight from the db using NotORM is not going to make the same 'MyClass' - from what I understand it will only have the data from the db.

Comment: Are you trying to create ORM with NotORM lib?

Comment: I don't think so. I basically want to be able to create an object from the db but I want it to be able to have extra methods that I have written myself.

Comment: Do you know what ORM mean?